# CMake linking glfw3 lib error

Tags: linux, c++11, linker, cmake, glfw

i'm working with CLion, and I'm writing a program using the glfw3 lib.(http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/)

I installed and did everything correctly for the lib i have the .a and .h files in:

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a

/usr/local/include/.h(all files)
```

I'm  trying to use the library now, but i'm getting the linker error:

`undefined reference to 'glViewport'` etc. etc. all the functions i'm using

I added the lib path to the make file, I can't understand what i'm doing wrong, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(testing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp examples.h)

add_executable(testing ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(testing /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a)
target_link_libraries(testing /usr/local/lib/libTest.a)

target_link_libraries(testing pthread)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not hard code absolute paths into your CMake files. This renders CMake useless.

In the [documentation of GLFW on how to link against it](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package), there it is explicitly written:

```
find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myapp
                      glfw
                      ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

---

Moreover, you can replace

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

with

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

and CMake will figure out the correct compiler flag automatically depending on the compiler currently in use.

Comment: You might want to add a line telling the OP *why* the OP gets the linker error, not only show what to do to fix it.

Comment: @Torbjörn the hardcoded string don't change anything. It might be that openGL requires different modules. but from the documentation dependencies, I added everything i need

Comment: @Mumfordwiz Except to link with the actual OpenGL library... :)

Comment: Wow, that is now very different. I've corrected the answer. I'm not quite sure whether it is `glfw` or `glfw3` in the `target_link_libraries` command. One of the two should work.

Comment: I'm guessing the package wasn't found because i'm getting target_include_directories called with invalid arguments. I tried following that guide before, but it just won't work

Comment: Debug the CMake variables (e.g. `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR`) by printing them out (via `message`) or inspect the CMake cache in CLion.

Comment: //Path to a file.
OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include

//Path to a library.
OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Comment: Error:target_include_directories called with invalid arguments what's wrong?

Comment: Mea culpa. I've forgot [the visibility specifier](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_include_directories.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the help.! it wokred!