# Correct way of adding libraries to C++ project

Tags: c++, git, cmake, libraries

In my project I want to include some libraries. For now at least `GLFW` and `GLEW`. 
I want them to be added automatically whenever I clone my repo. So my idea was to add those libraries as git-submodules and include them via my CMakeList. Both libs have a CMakeList which made me think I can easily add them with cmake.

But I don't know how to add those. I use CLion since I am not experienced with cmake or C++ in general. I tried to include them via `add_subdirectory()` and just treat them as normal code but then GLEW cant find header files, I tried to include them via `add_library()` but cmake does not use GLFWs CMakeList.

What would be the correct way of including libraries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39266802/3188346

Comment: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" (requested
  version 3.2)  EDIT: Found the link with sources in the GLFW documentation

Comment: @Exhauzt Add the path you installed glfw3 in to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable